# SQL SELECT statement from both tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 select statements which I want to grep the results of both table and display then a dropdown box. I am able to do it for each `SELECT` statement but I am unable to select from both at the same time.

Below are my 2 SELECT statements:

```
string loggedIn= (User.Identity.Name);

SELECT DISTINCT ReportTitle from HRPastReports WHERE [username] LIKE '%" + loggedIn + "%'";
SELECT DISTINCT ReportTitle from FinancePastReports WHERE [username] LIKE '%" + loggedIn+ "%'";
```

How can I combine both the `SELECT` statements in to a single one?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this only by `UNION` because you're referencing two different tables

```
SELECT DISTINCT ReportTitle from HRPastReports WHERE [username] LIKE '%" + loggedIn + "%'";
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ReportTitle from FinancePastReports WHERE [username] LIKE '%" + loggedIn+ "%'";
```

Comment: @rabuddle thank you, but how do I combine both the statement into one, as I need to form it into one single statement in my `SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT STATEMENT"`

Comment: Then `CREATE VIEW` over both tables, then you can do `SELECT` on the view, there's no other way

Answer (score 1):

you can use `UNION` operator like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ReportTitle from HRPastReports WHERE [username] LIKE '%" + loggedIn + "%'";
union all
SELECT DISTINCT ReportTitle from FinancePastReports WHERE [username] LIKE '%" + loggedIn+ "%'";
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` can result in duplicates! He's using `DISTINCT` so one can assume he wants to avoid duplicates

Comment: @Rashmi, thank you for the solution, but same as rabuddle, i would like to ask the same question. How do I combine both the statement into one, as I need to form it into one single statement in my `SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT STATEMENT"`

Comment: its a single satement you cant right like this
string str="SELECT DISTINCT ReportTitle from HRPastReports WHERE [username] LIKE '%" + loggedIn + "%'";
union all
SELECT DISTINCT ReportTitle from FinancePastReports WHERE [username] LIKE '%" + loggedIn+ "%'";";
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand =str;