# SQL Select Multiple Tables based on parameter

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been challenged on selecting on different tables based on a parameter.
My question will be pretty much similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381744/sql-select-statement-from-both-tables), but here is my case:

Say I have a parameter list from the front end [1,2,3,4]

And based on this parameter, how can I do select on the different tables on an sql?

In Java, I can do:

```
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
if ( parameter == 1)
    sql.append("Select * from TABLEA");
else if  ( parameter == 2)
    sql.append("Select * from TABLEB");
else if  ( parameter == 3)
    sql.append("Select * from TABLEC");
else if  ( parameter == 4)
    sql.append("Select * from TABLED");
```

How can I do this on SQL itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Oracle PLSQL`, you can do it somewhat like this:

```
PROCEDURE TEST(
        o_retcd OUT NUMBER,
        o_errmsg OUT VARCHAR2,
        o_currStatus IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
        i_type IN VARRAY --your parameters
              ) 
BEGIN

FOR i IN i_type.FIRST..i_type.LAST
    LOOP
         if i_type(i) = 1 then
          OPEN o_currStatus FOR
            select * from TABLEA;
         elsif i_type(i) = 2 then
          OPEN o_currStatus FOR
            select * from TABLEB;
         elsif i_type(i) = 3 then
          OPEN o_currStatus FOR
            select * from TABLEC;
         elsif i_type(i) = 4 then
          OPEN o_currStatus FOR
            select * from TABLED;
         end if;
    END LOOP;

  EXCEPTION
 --Exception handling
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
      o_retcd := 100;

END;
```

Comment: hmm, can I ask, why do you have to do:
    FOR i IN i_type.FIRST..i_type.LAST ?

Comment: so you could iterate through your `i_type` array. you could pass your [1,2,3,4] as a parameter `i_type`

Comment: I will be passing in as a parameter from a dropdown list, so is the for loop still applicable?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Read about [`Dynamic SQL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm).</strike>

Basically, it would be something along the lines of

```
  l_query :=    'select * from ' 
             || case l_param 
                when 1 then 'table1'
                when 2 then 'table2'
                end;
```

And then you use this string to open a cursor, having several options to do this depending on what your query actually does.

Didn't read your question carefully. If you want a *pure sql* solution, then there is probably none. Well, maybe only using `union all` to concatenate result sets from different tables (assuming they have similar structure) and then filter it by your parameter value.

**update**:
Another option would be something like this - generating XML and querying it, but I am not entirely sure it is a good practice :)

```
10:54:40 SYSTEM@dwh-prod> l                                    
  1  select *                                                  
  2    from xmltable(                                          
  3       '/ROWSET/*'                                          
  4       passing xmltype(                                     
  5          dbms_xmlgen.getxml(                               
  6            'select * from '                                
  7            || case :param                                  
  8               when 1 then 'all_objects'                    
  9               when 2 then 'user_objects'                   
 10               else 'dba_objects'                           
 11               end                                          
 12            ||'  where rownum < 10'                         
 13           )                                                
 14       )                                                    
 15       columns                                              
 16       object_name varchar2(100) path '//ROW/OBJECT_NAME',  
 17       object_type varchar2(100) path '//ROW/OBJECT_TYPE',  
 18       status      varchar2(100) path '//ROW/STATUS'        
 19*    )                                                      
10:54:40 SYSTEM@dwh-prod> exec :param := 1;                    

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.                       

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01                                           
10:55:00 SYSTEM@dwh-prod> /                                    

OBJECT_NAME          OBJECT_TYPE          STATUS               
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- 
CON$                 TABLE                VALID                
I_COL2               INDEX                VALID                
I_USER#              INDEX                VALID                
C_TS#                CLUSTER              VALID                
I_OBJ#               INDEX                VALID                
I_CON2               INDEX                VALID                
I_OBJ5               INDEX                VALID                
IND$                 TABLE                VALID                
BOOTSTRAP$           TABLE                VALID                

9 rows selected.                                               

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04                                           
10:55:01 SYSTEM@dwh-prod> exec :param := 2;                    

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.                       

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00                                           
10:55:06 SYSTEM@dwh-prod> /                                    

OBJECT_NAME          OBJECT_TYPE          STATUS               
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- 
AQ$DEF$_AQCALL       VIEW                 VALID                
AQ$DEF$_AQERROR      VIEW                 VALID                
AQ$_DEF$_AQCALL_E    QUEUE                VALID                
AQ$_DEF$_AQCALL_F    VIEW                 VALID                
AQ$_DEF$_AQERROR_E   QUEUE                VALID                
AQ$_DEF$_AQERROR_F   VIEW                 VALID                
AQ$_INTERNET_AGENTS  TABLE                VALID                
AQ$_INTERNET_AGENT_P TABLE                VALID                
AQ$_QUEUES           TABLE                VALID

9 rows selected.                               

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
```

Comment: So, do we have to use procedure to do the select?

Comment: Ah. I don't think my upper side would want to use xml, procedure should be good. thanks.